# Handling Errors In Angular Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am still learning promises in angular and have this bit of code where I am making a "GET" request two times. I want to run one get request before calling the other. This is working fine, but how would I handle errors here? If I get an error for my first GET request how do I find out what that error is and prevent my code from calling the second GET request? Examples with my code would be most helpful.

```
apiServices.login = function(user,password,callback) {
$http.get("http://magainteractive.com/prototypes/cisco-ima-dashboard/cms/web/api/login/login/?username="+user+"&password="+password+"")
        .then(function(contentResponse){
            resultsObject.content = contentResponse; 
            return $http.get("http://magainteractive.com/prototypes/cisco-ima-dashboard/cms/web/api/data/list/"); 
        })
        .then(function(dataResponse){
            resultsObject.reports = dataResponse;
            resultsObject.success = 1;
            console.log(resultsObject);

            callback(resultsObject);
            apiServices.useData(resultsObject);
        }); 
}

dummyData.login(username, password, function (dataStatus) {

            if (dataStatus.success = 1) {

                $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
                $rootScope.selectedDashboard = 1; 
            } else {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do things slightly different from Lucas, I prefer chaining a catch block( basically it would act like the synchrounous `try...catch` block we use) rather than adding an error callback function so code would be like:

```
return $http.get(url1)
  .then(function(result){
    resultsObject.url1 = result;
    return $http.get(url2);
  }).then(function(result){
    resultsObject.url2 = result;
    return resultsObject;
  }).catch(function(error){
    // handle error.
  });
```

P.S: most of your code is fine, but I am not really sure why you have that `callback(resultsObject);`, when you are using promises, callbacks are redundant, you could just return the promise chain `$http.get...`

Comment: I work this way too, I think it's pretty neat to chain a `catch` at the end! I totally agree with you.

Comment: @mido thanks! I edited my answer to show you why I am using callback. I use it to bring the resultsObject into my login controller as "dataStatus". This will check if my login credentials are true.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a second parameter in the first callback handling. This will trigger if there's an error in the request, then you can handle it however you want:

```
 $http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/someUrl'
 }).then(function successCallback(response) {
     // this callback will be called asynchronously
     // when the response is available
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
     // called asynchronously if an error occurs     
     // or server returns response with an error status.
   });
```

Or in your coding:

```
$http.get('/someUrl').then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

More information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Your code would look like:

```
$http.get("http://magainteractive.com/prototypes/cisco-ima-dashboard/cms/web/api/login/login/?username="+user+"&password="+password+"")
    .then(function(contentResponse){
        resultsObject.content = contentResponse; 
        return $http.get("http://magainteractive.com/prototypes/cisco-ima-dashboard/cms/web/api/data/list/"); 
    }, function(error){ 
             //HANDLE ERROR HERE
       })
    .then(function(dataResponse){
        resultsObject.reports = dataResponse;
        resultsObject.success = 1;
        console.log(resultsObject);

        callback(resultsObject);
        apiServices.useData(resultsObject);
    });
```

Comment: this looks good but what if I wanted error handling for both http requests? Would I add another function(error) after the second then function?

Comment: Exactly. In my example, the last line would change from `}); ` to: `}, function (error) { //asd }); `